# How to convert string to SolidColorBrush in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, string, solidcolorbrush

I'm trying to convert a `string` to a `SolidColorBrush` in C#. The code I'm using is:

```
arrColors[arrColors.Length - 1] = 
                         (SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFromString(sLine);
```

where sLine is a string read from a text file. For example, `sLine` might be "Black".

This code gives me a `FormatException`.

Answer (score 8):

Assuming all of your brushes are solid colours, you could construct a Color from a string as follows:

```
Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(sLine);
```

Then you could create a `SolidColorBrush` from that colour, like so:

```
SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
```

**EDIT**: If the string being converted is English but the current culture is not, you may need to use `ConvertFromInvariantString` instead, like so:

```
ColorConverter converter = new ColorConverter();
Color color = (Color)converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(sLine);
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there any using statement for Color.FromName i need to use? Now it gives me that 'System.Windows.Media.Color' does not contain a definition for 'FromName'.

Comment: Yes @TaW. Fact is that there are several colors that go into my array. So i cant use Color.FromName("Black") or something like that.

Comment: @NielsBril: I've adapted the solution to work for the WPF classes, I didn't realise that was what you were using.

Comment: @NielsBril I've edited my solution again; I'm assuming from your source code example that the wrong CultureInfo may be used. In that case then the invariant culture should be used instead.

Comment: @Quackmatic still not solved :( i can't use the ConvertFromInvariantString method. is there any way to send you the project?

Comment: It seems `ConvertFromInvariantString` is an instance method (for some reason.) Create an instance of ColorConverter instead of calling it statically; see my answer.

Comment: @Quackmatic i really dont get it, when i use breakpoints my array is filled with the hexadecimal colors, but still it gives me formatexception

Comment: Can you give the actual message of the exception? Preferably translated into English if it isn't already.

Comment: @Quackmatic here is the project:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfv7r81gcnwv284/8Oefening3.rar?dl=0

sorry for bothering you

Comment: That doesn't help. I can't help you unless you give me the exact message of the Exception being thrown.

Comment: @Quackmatic thanks already: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0dbvbejoa51sar0/formatexception.PNG?dl=0

Comment: What is the exact content of `sKleur` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: string sKleur = sLine; and sLine is read 6 times (Black, Green, etc). Kleur is Dutch for color ;)

Comment: Try replacing `sKleur` with `sKleur.Trim()` in the call to `ConvertFromInvariantString`. There may be leading or trailing whitespace in the string.

Comment: @Quackmatic still doesnt work, but dont bother about it anymore, i will ask my teacher next week. thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(sLine);
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
```